# asp.net core SignalR configuration in ASP.NET Web Application (.NET framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

how can i configure asp.net core signalr in ASP.NET Web Application (.NET framework 4.6.2 or higher) web project?
from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1#how-to-identify-the-signalr-version) this should be possible, but i cant find any way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not supported.
The server type required for asp.net core signal r is asp.net core. 
The normal "system.web" pipeline would not be compatible with the asp.net core SignalR.

In my opinion, you will be able to use CLIENT package - only if your application is client to asp.net core web api.