# Can I use ASP.NET Core SignalR Javascript file in my .NET Framework Web appplication?

Tags: signalr

I have a Web application that uses the .NET Framework.  I created a separate ASP.NET Core web application to use as a SignalR server.

In the .NET Framework web app, I followed the Microsoft tutorial on adding the Javascript client libraries (@microsoft/signalr@latest).

The chat application is working, but then I saw this statement "ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR."  [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-7.0#how-to-identify-the-signalr-version)

I get that there is no backwards compatibility, but is this *also* saying that if your application is using the .NET Framework, you must use ASP.NET SignalR for both client and server?

I found this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158697/asp-net-core-signalr-configuration-in-asp-net-web-application-net-framework) which seems to indicate that it is okay, but I'm not sure what he means by "normal System.Web" pipeline.

Comment: That's fine. The docs are saying you can't use a non-core server with a core client, or vice-versa. But since you're using a core server and core client it's fine.

Comment: Don't let the "Core" in "ASP.NET Core SignalR" trip you up. It's really poor naming convention that creates confusion. It has nothing to do with .NET CORE 1/2/3/4 or .NET 5, 6 or 7. It only references the "core" components in ASP.NET SignalR.

Comment: Thanks.  It makes searching a pain too.  I wish MS would have added an identifier to the core version like SignalR2022 or something like that.